# XCode 8 keeps freezing at startup when loading index

Tags: ios, xcode, ide

My xCode 8 keeps freezing at startup when loading the index of the project. I have to delete the derived folder data everytime to make XCode not freezing (and thus it has to rebuild the index everytime).  I always had this problem since XCode8 has released and there has not been a fix yet. The problem did not exist when I use XCode7 (even though indexing was also very slow, it did not freeze and will eventually finish).

I suspect that loading the index may take too much memory (my dev machine has 8GB of RAM). Does anyone notice the same problem and is there a solution for it?

Our company's project is decently large (around 200-300 source files).

My XCode is the AppStore public version: Version 8.0 (8A218a).

Comment: Do you have the app store version?

Comment: Yes, this is the app store public version, not the GM or Beta.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
rm -f Index
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue, and my solution is:

Restart my `Xcode`, then there is no `Loading index...`